# Render method should have a return statement. Fetch data via mongoose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-bootstrap

I am learning ReactJS, NodeJS, ExpressJS and building a page where you submit something (a post) to a feed (mongoDB database via API) and after refreshing the page, you get the posts below the form where you type the text.

I am getting the following error:
"*Failed to compile
./src/components/this_file.js
Line 22:3:  Your render method should have return statement  react/require-render-return
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.*"

Can anyone please explain or provide an article from where I can learn what I did wrong and how to fix this rendering issue?
Because from what I can see, I do have a return statement after render.

The code is the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import styles from './layout.module.css'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

// SERVICES
import productService from '../services/productService';

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ''
    }
  }

  render() {

    const [feeds, setfeed] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!feeds) {
    getContent();
  }
})


const getContent = async () => {
  let res = await productService.getFeed();
  console.log(res);
  setfeed(res);
}

const renderFeed = feed => {
  return (
        <>
        <Layout>
        <Helmet>
        <title>Feed</title>
        </Helmet>
        <Container>

        <br /><br /><br />
        {/* <h5>Start typing...</h5> */}

        <form id="feed-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">

        <Form.Group>

         <Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            rows="10"
            name="feed"
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray'}}
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            Post visible after page refresh.
          </Form.Text>
          
        </Form.Group>

          <Button type="submit" style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', border: 'grey' }}> 
            Submit
          </Button>
          
        </form><br />

        <Card border="dark" text="light" key={feed._id}>
        <Card.Body>
            {feed.content}<br /><br />
          <Card.Text className="text-right">
            <small className="text-muted">{formatDate(feed.date)}</small>
          </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        </Card>
        <br />

        {(feeds && feeds.length > 0) ? (
          feeds.map(feed => renderFeed(feed))
        ) : (
          <p>No feed found</p>
        )}

<div className={styles.backToHome}>
      <a href="/" className="link">
        ← Back to home
      </a>
    </div>
        </Container>
        </Layout>
        </>
  );
}
  }

  onMessageChange(event) {
    this.setState({content: event.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/feed', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(
      (response) => (response.json())
        ).then((response)=> {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
      } else if(response.status === 'fail') {
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
    })
  }
}

function formatDate( string ) {
  var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' };
  return new Date( string ).toLocaleDateString([], options);
}

export default App;
```

Thank you

Comment: As the error says your `render()` method is not returning anything. You have return statements in the functions you defined inside the render method but that doesnt do a return for the render method itself

Comment: Your `render() {` function, declaration right under the `contructor()` should be at the very end of the class component and inside it there should only be jsx that you want to render to the screen.

Comment: Another key issue is that hooks like `useEffect` with class components, they can only be used with functional components.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the answers.

Here is the final form, bois:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import styles from './layout.module.css'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contents: []
    }
  }

  state = {
    hasErrors: false,
    content: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/feed")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ contents: res }))
      .catch(() => this.setState({ hasErrors: true }));
  }

  render() {

    const { contents } = this.state

  return (
        <>
        <Layout>
        <Helmet>
        <title>Feed</title>
        </Helmet>
        <Container>

        <br /><br /><br />
        {/* <h5>Start typing...</h5> */}

        <form id="feed-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">

        <Form.Group>

         <Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            rows="10"
            name="feed"
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray'}}
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            Post visible after page refresh.
          </Form.Text>
          
        </Form.Group>

          <Button type="submit" style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', border: 'grey' }}> 
            Submit
          </Button>
          
        </form><br />

        {contents.map((item, index) => 
       <> <Card border="dark" text="light">
                      
                          <Card.Body>
                              {item.content}<br /><br />
                            <Card.Text className="text-right">
                              <small className="text-muted">{formatDate(item.date)}</small>
                            </Card.Text>
                          </Card.Body>
                      
                        </Card><br/></>
        )}

<div className={styles.backToHome}>
      <a href="/" className="link">
        ← Back to home
      </a>
    </div>
        </Container>
        </Layout>
        </>
  );
}

  onMessageChange(event) {
    this.setState({content: event.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/feed', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(
      (response) => (response.json())
        ).then((response)=> {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
      } else if(response.status === 'fail') {
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
    })
  }
}

function formatDate( string ) {
  var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' };
  return new Date( string ).toLocaleDateString([], options);
}

export default App;
```

Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Return something in your render method... for ex.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
   return (<renderFeed/>)
}
```

However your class component `class App extends React.Component` is using function component methods mixed in and thats not allowed. Either refactor the App component to also be a functional component or use the "classic" lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main problem is that you are using a mix of methods from class based components and functional components, which I would recommend fixing first.

For example, this is how you set up state in a class based component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: ''
    };
  }
```

And this is how you set it up in a functional component.

```
const [feeds, setfeed] = useState(null);
```

However, you have a combination of both. You will need to decide whether you want a class component or functional component.

If you want to use the `useState` or `useEffect` hooks, for example, you would need to turn this into a functional component.

[Here is an explanation of the difference between the two](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Also, inside of the render() function, you do not return anything.

You do have a `renderFeed` function with a return statement, but that return statement is not within the scope of the render() function.